# Use javascript to write CSS specificity function

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, string-comparison, css-specificity

I need to write a javascript function, which compares two arguments passed in.  They will be strings.  And represent CSS classes.

The aim of the function, is to weight CSS specificity.  So if an argument passed in, is a CSS ID, it should be returned rather than the second argument.  (EG if a = '#id', it will beat b = '.red').

Kinda getting lost on the best approach for my javascript function.  Not sure whether to use if/else statements or switch/case.  Either way, it's getting messy and need some pointers.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- compare argument a to b, which both are strings.
- If a css class entered is an id, (eg '#id'), this trumps all other css classes.  So return this.
- if css class is a tagname, an ID still beats this. So return the ID.
- If '*' is entered, this has no specificity, so any other class beats this.
- A class selector beats a tagname. (eg div.red > p).

  ```
  // '*' weakest - anything beats this
  // tagname beats '*'. EG 'div' beats '*'
  // 2 tagnames beats 1 tagname - EG 'div div' beats 'p'
  // class selector beats tagname - EG 'div.red' beats 'div'
  // id is strongest #id - '#ID' beats all the above


  function compare(a,b){

    const low = '*';
    const tagname = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    const twoTagnames = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;


    if (a === low) {
      a < b;
      return b;
    } else (b === low); {
      b < a;
      return a;
    }

    if (a.includes('#')) {
      a < b;
      return b;
   } else if (b.includes('#')) {
      b < a;
     return a;
   }

  }

  compare('*','#id');
  ```

Comment: I would use the following document as reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @codeWonderland - thank you, i know what css specificity is.  I need help on writing a javascript function, which compares css classes, passed into a javascript function.  To return the class which weights higher.

Comment: https://github.com/keeganstreet/specificity

Comment: @AuxTaco - Thank you, but i'm not using React. I need to do this in Vanilla JS!

Comment: @ReenaVerma I don't think the past two comments that were sent in were meant to be solutions to your problem, they were just suggestions on how to get started on building them yourself. If they were solutions they would show up as an answer you can mark as the correct solution

Comment: Who said anything about React? `specificity.mjs` (generated from [`specificity.js`](https://github.com/keeganstreet/specificity/blob/master/specificity.js)) is vanilla.

Comment: @AuxTaco - it's suggested to import, use node... i'm just doing this raw. thanks though

Comment: @codeWonderland - i know, just looking for someone to help me figure that best way to start writing this. thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this exact question recently during a job interview and I was able to figure it out like so:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  let aItems = a.split([" "]);
  let aRating = [0, 0, 0];

  aItems.forEach((i) => {
    if (i.split("#").length > 1) {
      aRating[0] = aRating[0] + (i.split("#").length - 1);
    }

    if (i.split(".").length > 1) {
      aRating[1] = aRating[1] + (i.split(".").length - 1);
    }

    if (!i.startsWith("#") && !i.startsWith(".")) {
      aRating[2] = aRating[2] + 1;
    }
  });

  let bItems = b.split([" "]);
  let bRating = [0, 0, 0];

  bItems.forEach((i) => {
    if (i.split("#").length > 1) {
      bRating[0] = bRating[0] + (i.split("#").length - 1);
    }

    if (i.split(".").length > 1) {
      bRating[1] = bRating[1] + (i.split(".").length - 1);
    }

    if (!i.startsWith("#") && !i.startsWith(".")) {
      bRating[2] = bRating[2] + 1;
    }
  });

  if (aRating[0] > bRating[0]) {
    return a;
  } else if (bRating[0] > aRating[0]) {
    return b;
  }

  if (aRating[1] > bRating[1]) {
    return a;
  } else if (bRating[1] > aRating[1]) {
    return b;
  } else if (
    bRating[0] === aRating[0] &&
    bRating[2] === 0 &&
    aRating[2] === 0
  ) {
    return b;
  }

  if (aRating[2] > bRating[2]) {
    return a;
  } else if (bRating[2] > aRating[2]) {
    return b;
  }
}
```

There is one issue though, say you are comparing `tagnames` (ie, `html`, `body` where the more specific, the higher the specificity), then you might have some difficulty. I was able to hack my way through it string of if else tests.

Comment: "html, body where the more specific, the higher the specificity" This isn't true. They're equally specific.

Comment: Per the test, one or the other took precedent(I don't remember which one). As I mentioned the whole test was a bit hacky imo. However, the remaining code is sound and you should get the appropriate specificity.

Comment: Ahh, you were referring to an issue in your solution. My bad, I misread. Incidentally, I envy you getting such an interview question! I'd gobble it up. (I'm the author of an answer someone else linked to in your question.)