# Get the formula of a CSS value instead of the calculated value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

Any quick way to get the formula of a CSS value instead of the calculated version of it?

I.e I'm trying to get `calc(100vh - 305px)`, but I'm instead getting the calculated result; `"542.984375px"`.

I'm using this code to get the value in the Safari console:

```
window.getComputedStyle($0).getPropertyValue('height');
```

Answer (score 1):

Without much thinking:

- find CSS rules applied to the element
- sort them by specificity https://stackoverflow.com/a/67144451/14098260
- return the first rule

```js
const width = findRule(document.querySelector('.test'), 'width');
console.log(width);

function findRule(elem, name) {
    const found = [];
    for (const {cssRules} of document.styleSheets) {
        for (const {style, selectorText} of cssRules) {
            const value = style?.[name];
            value && 
              elem.matches(selectorText) && 
                found.push([selectorText, value]);
        }
    }
    // sort by specificity
    found.sort(([a], [b]) => {
      const applied = compare(a, b);
      return applied === a? -1: 1;
    });
    return found[0][1];
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/67144451/14098260
function compare(a, b) {

  let aItems = a.split([" "]);
  let aRating = [0, 0, 0];

  aItems.forEach((i) => {
    if (i.split("#").length > 1) {
      aRating[0] = aRating[0] + (i.split("#").length - 1);
    }

    if (i.split(".").length > 1) {
      aRating[1] = aRating[1] + (i.split(".").length - 1);
    }

    if (!i.startsWith("#") && !i.startsWith(".")) {
      aRating[2] = aRating[2] + 1;
    }
  });

  let bItems = b.split([" "]);
  let bRating = [0, 0, 0];

  bItems.forEach((i) => {
    if (i.split("#").length > 1) {
      bRating[0] = bRating[0] + (i.split("#").length - 1);
    }

    if (i.split(".").length > 1) {
      bRating[1] = bRating[1] + (i.split(".").length - 1);
    }

    if (!i.startsWith("#") && !i.startsWith(".")) {
      bRating[2] = bRating[2] + 1;
    }
  });

  if (aRating[0] > bRating[0]) {
    return a;
  } else if (bRating[0] > aRating[0]) {
    return b;
  }

  if (aRating[1] > bRating[1]) {
    return a;
  } else if (bRating[1] > aRating[1]) {
    return b;
  } else if (
    bRating[0] === aRating[0] &&
    bRating[2] === 0 &&
    aRating[2] === 0
  ) {
    return b;
  }

  if (aRating[2] > bRating[2]) {
    return a;
  } else if (bRating[2] > aRating[2]) {
    return b;
  }
}
```

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solit #777;
}
div.test{
  width: calc(100vw - 100px);
}
.test{
  background: #aaa;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>Test</div>
```

Comment: Whoa, this is really impressive! I've thought about trying this approach but thought it would be too brittle to be reliable. From a glance I guess current version will skip non-root rules: those wrapped `@media`, `@layer`, `@container` blocks, (paused) animation, and would potentially give false answers from non-applied `<style media="not screen">`. And it does not consider `!important` origin. But otherwise it looks super promising, thanks for whipping it up.

Comment: yes, i think the direction is right, maybe needs some tweaks which is up to you for your particular case. there could be an element's  `style` attribute processing also. if you find my answer useful don't hesitate to upvote it (arrow up) and accept (checkbox). that way i will get reputation and will be motivated to help you in the future, thanks

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much for your answer! Unfortunately, when I inject this into Safari, I get the error: `SecurityError: Not allowed to access cross-origin stylesheet`.

Comment: @David could you give the link to your stylesheet? and the element's HTML. i'll try to solve that

Comment: Hey @AlexanderNenashev, I'm working with https://careers.walmart.com in particular for this issue (more specifically the container grid grid--spaced grid--bottom div element), however as this is a browser for a unique environment, I need something to work with most/all sites. Even something to change 'vh' without resizing the window would be great.